# Different outputs on vs code and replit.com

Tags: c, output, post-increment, pre-increment, replit

I am trying to run this code which is written in C language. It is giving different outputs when run on VS code and Replit.com. I am confused. Please explain

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 6, z = 0;
    printf("\n x=%d \n z=%d \n y=%d", x, z, y);
    printf("\n xpo=%d \n xpre=%d \n xpos=%d", x++, ++x, x++);
    return 0;
}
```

VS code is giving the following output:

```
x=1
z=0
y=6
xpo=3
xpre=4
xpos=1
```

And replit.com is giving this output:

```
x=1
z=0
y=6
xpo=1
xpre=3
xpos=3
```

Comment: There is no difference between the two versions of output shown in the question.

Comment: I see that OP has now fixed the question in an edit, and has added the question for review for reopening. In my opinion, the question should stay closed, because it is a duplicate. However, after OP fixed the question, I removed my downvote and replaced it with an upvote. In my opinion, the question is useful now, because it serves as a signpost to the duplicate question.